# Finding a sequence in a string of characters and printing it out along with characters following it

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to create a program in Perl that will read through thousands of characters that and attempt to find a matching string of characters. I need to print out the string plus the next five letters. I also need to print out the location of where it was found, i.e. how many letters in. I am pretty new to Perl. I'm just learning it in class now.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$sequence = 'abcd';
$fileName = 'file.txt';

#Opening file
unless (open(fileName, $fileName)) {
    print "Cannot open file.";
    exit;
}
@tempArr = <fileName>;    #Adding the lines to an array
close fileName;           #closing the file
$characters = join('', @tempArr);    #making it a clean string
$characters =~ s/\s//g;               #removing white lines
if (characters =~ m/$sequence/i) {

    #Print $sequence and next five characters
}
else {
    print "Does not contain the sequence.";
}

exit;
```

file.txt will look like:

```
aajbkjklasjlksjadlasjdaljasdlkajs
aabasdajlakjdlasdjkalsdkjalsdkjds
askdjakldamwnemwnamsndjawekljadsa
abcassdadadfaasabsadfabcdhereeakj
```

I need to print out the "abcdheree"

Comment: Please, indentation is really important, and most when you ask help. That will help you too, trust me.

Comment: I followed the guide on how to format it for code, it says make it 8 indents in. I did that, then went through and added more, but it still turned out like this. I kept hitting tab to indent, but it jumped down lines, so I knew at the time some lines might be bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print `$sequence` & the 5 characters after it, try using :

```
if ($characters =~ m/$sequence.{5}/i) {
    print "$&\n";
```

(You forgot the `$` on `characters`)

**NOTE**

- `.` mean any character
- `{5}` is a quantifier
- when using `open`, use 3 arguments like : `open my $fh, "<", "$file" or die $!;` See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html
- always put `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of your script
- don't forget `$` on variables (you miss many ones)
- use `my` for declaring variables
- maybe a better approach than making one big string: you can process the array line by line like : `foreach my $line (@tempArr) { #process $line }`
- you call the array `@melTemp1` that is never declared

**FINALLY**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

my $sequence = 'abcd';
my $fileName = 'file.txt';

#Opening file
open my $fh, "<", $fileName or die "Cannot open file. [$!]";

my @tempArr = <$fh>;                    #Putting the file handle into an array
close $fileName;                        #closing the file handle

my $characters = join('', @tempArr);    #making it a big string
$characters =~ s/\s//g;                 #removing white spaces & tabs

if ($characters =~ m/$sequence.{5}/i) {
    print "$&\n";
}
else {
    print "Does not contain the sequence.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot in a few minutes. I have the original $ in my actual code. This is code that is very similar to it.